# keyboard focus issue in textfield (Codenameone)

Tags: codenameone

I have a textfield in dialog box. When I try to type smth in it, it just goes out. What just happened here. I have captured the video. please have a look. https://youtu.be/HhwoPWJDG1M

Code:

```
super(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
setScrollableY(false);
Container mainContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));
add(mainContainer);
Label logo = new Label();
mainContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, logo);
Button forgotPassword = new Button("FORGOT PASSWORD");
- - - - - - - - - - - -
//r components added to main form
- - - - - - - - - - - -
Container centerContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(userNameField, passwordSection, forgotPassword);
mainContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, centerContainer);


TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(1, 2);
Container passwordSection = new Container(tl);
passwordSection.add(tl.createConstraint().
    widthPercentage(80),passwordField).
    add(tl.createConstraint().verticalAlign(Component.CENTER).widthPercentage(19), sendButton);

**//this is the dialog box where problem exists**
forgotPassword.addActionListener(e -> {
    Dialog d = new Dialog();
    TextField emailTextField = new TextField();
    emailTextField.setHint("Enter your email here");
    d.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    d.add(emailTextField);
    Button submit = new Button("Submit");
    d.add(submit);
    d.showPopupDialog(logo);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from using `showPopup()` Dialog and not keeping it from autoDisposing. Use one of `showPacked()` or `showStretched()` and define its position, then set the dialog `autoDispose()` to false:

```
d.setAutoDispose(false); //reason dialog is disposing quickly
d.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true);
d.showPacked(BorderLayout.NORTH, true);
```